# How to pass custom objects from Play Framework filters to controllers?

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to pass a custom object from my play essential filter to my controller. How can I achieve this.

Sample filter:

```
class CustomFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter {
  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    // along with request header I want to pass a custom object
    nextFilter(requestHeader)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? What's the goal?

Comment: I have an auth filter from which I want to pass the session object into the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Request Attributes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Highlights26#Request-attributes):

```scala
object Attrs {
  val whatever: TypedKey[WhatEver] = TypedKey.apply[WhatEver]("we")
}

// in your filter:
val newReq = req.addAttr(Attrs.whatever, WhatEver(...))
nextFilter(newReq)

// in your action function:
val whatever: WhatEver = req.attrs(Attrs.WhatEver) 
// OR -- for extra safety
val whatever: Option[WhatEver] = req.attrs.get(Attrs.WhatEver)
```